Training labels in classification models, in the context of LLMs
I’m taking a course on LLMs, and our instructor said something that led me to an idea and a question. On the topic of instruction fine tuning, he said:

The training dataset should be many prompt-completion pairs, each of which should contain an instruction. During fine tuning, you select prompts from the training dataset and pass them to the LLM which then generates completions. Next, you compare the LLM completions with the response specified from the training data. Remember, the output of a LLM is a probability distribution across tokens. So you can compare the distribution of the completion and that of the training label, and use the standard cross-entropy function to calculate loss between the two token distributions.

I’m asking the question in the context of LLMs, but this same concept could apply to supervised learning in general. Instead of labels being a single “correct” answer, what if they were distributions of potentially correct answers?
For example, if the prompt were:
“Classify this review: It wasn’t bad.”
Instead of labelling the sentiment as “Positive”, what if we wanted the result to be “Positive” 60% of the time, and “Neutral” 40% of the time.
Asked another way, instead of treating classification problems as only having one correct answer, have people experimented with training classification models (LLMs or otherwise) where the correct answer was a set of labels each with a different probability distribution? My intuition is that this might help prevent models from overfitting and may help them generalize better. Especially since in real life things rarely fit neatly into categories.

If I understand you correctly, you are speaking of something that is known as soft-labeling.
According to Galstyan and Cohen (2007):
"A soft label is one which has a score (probability or likelihood) attached to it. So the element is a member of the class in question with probability/likelihood score of eg 0.7; this implies that an element can be a member of multiple classes (presumably with different membership scores), which is usually not possible with hard labels."
There has been research in this direction, both for traditional machine learning models and for neural networks including LLMs, some of which are:

Label Smoothing
Confidence Calibration

Nowadays there are many applications where this is used such as medical diagnosis models and Image Classification models (generally cases where multiple conditions are possible or multiple subjects), also others as well. The potential benefits in terms of model performance, generalization are quite promissing.
Here are some NVIDIA DeepLearning examples where you can find for example this utilization inside Image Classification section.

That was exactly what I was asking about. Thank you for providing some links to resources on the topic.
